# How to get a grafana annotation table based on the dashbord configuration?

Tags: annotations, grafana

I would like to get a table in my grafana dashboard that lists all annotations shown on the dashboard (gathered via dashboard configuration and (if possible) also the ones contained in panels.

Any idea? I cannot find a detailed documentation on that...

Comment: Try: https://community.grafana.com/t/table-of-annotations-in-grafana-7/32388

Comment: @JanGaraj Thank you! I would vote as the correct answer but you wrote a comment... The problem here is really that it is alpha... But there is potential ;-)

Comment: Unfortunately, just link to the another page is not good for the answer, so it is good only for the comment.